# How many ways can the group $\mathbb Z_5$ act on the set $\{1,2,...5\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many ways can the group $\mathbb Z_5$ act on the set $\{1,2,...5\}$.What is the problem demanding ? How to approach it .Please give the way too approach it not the solution

Comment: The action of a group $G$ on a set $S$ is a homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut}(S)$, where $\operatorname{Aut}(S)$ is the set of (arbitrary) bijections $S \to S$. For the computation in this particular case, note that any action of $\mathbb{Z}_5 = \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ factors through an action of $\mathbb{Z}$, and the latter is easy to compute.

Comment: what's the meaning of "factors through an action " please explain @anomaly.By the way can u post an answer please in this respect

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a group and $X$ a set. Then a group action of $G$ on $X$ is a homomorphism

$f:G\rightarrow\ S_X$. Thus problem reduces to number of Homomorphism

$f:\Bbb Z_5\rightarrow\ S_5$. Which can be determined by founding the permutation of order dividing 5. So the number of ways in which $\Bbb Z_5$ can act on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is given by ${5!\over5}+1 = 25$